Directory issue
I sent the flutter application I was working on from one pc to another and now when I run it on the new pc  and now the error is I'm getting the directory of the previous pc so the app can't run..
How can I fix this issue.
I didn't think the directory will affect the app
Below is the error
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

Failed to create parent directory 'C:\Users\name' when creating directory 'C:\Users\name\Documents\Flutter VS codes\ecommerce\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets'


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


And when you followed the suggestions... ?

Run flutter clean in project terminal before moving it to another PC, and then flutter pub get on the new PC
